# J-K flip-flops TTL to CMOS

Tags: flipflop, cmos, ttl

The following uses 3 TTL 74SLS76N J-K flip-flops, which are active low:

[image]

However, I'm trying to figure out what the settings for the PR and CLR inputs would be using CMOS CD4027 J-K flip-flops. For example, would the PR and CLR inputs be the inverse of the ones shown above for the number 2 using CMOS: 01 10 01?

Comment: The 7404 is a hex inverter, not a flipflop.  What is the correct part number?

Comment: Sorry about that.  The correct part number for the TTL JK flip flop is 74LS76N

Comment: Yes, the CD4027 has active high set and clear, so just invert your settings.